# How to do predicate pushdown with array_contains and ElasticSearch data source?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to query an array in ElasticSearch

```
data: "names":[{"name":"allen"},{"name":"bill"},{"name":"dave"},{"name":"poter"}]
goal: "select names from table where array_contains(names.name, "bill")"
```

but spark won't do predicate pushdown if SQL statement use `array_contains` function.
    `hint: names.name = ["allen","bill","dave","poter"]`
I've tried

```
select * from table where array_contains(names.name,"bill") 
-- and  
select explode(names.name) as name from table as t1;select * from t1 where name = "bill" 
-- and  
select * from table where cast(names.name as string) like '%bill%'
```

All failed to do pushdown, any other ways to do it?

Comment: It may be dependent on data source. Which data source you are using ?

Comment: @Nirmal Elasticsearch 5.4.1, may depends on the package?I'm using org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11:5.5.0

Comment: Best bet may be to filter by query while loading the dataframe itself . I don't think array_contains gets pushed down .

Comment: @Nirmal I know, I am asking if there were some other SQL statements that can finish the goal and spark sql can manage to pushdown

Comment: @Nirmal But spark2.2.0 supported `array_contains`

Comment: it needs to be supported in driver as well . Also i am not very sure if array_contains get pushed down with different data sources ( like UDFS are not pushed down )

Answer (score 6):

The failure to pushdown is expected. For predicate to be delegated you need a Data Source support, and ElasticSearch connector doesn't list `array_contains` among [pushed operations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html#spark-pushdown), which as today include:

- `=`, `=>` , `<`, `>=` , `<=`
- `is_null` / `is_not_null`
- `in`
- `String[Starts|Ends]With`, `StringContains`
- `NULL` safe equality.
- Application of Boolean operators `AND` / `OR` / `NOT`.

Also any additional transformations (including `CAST`) disable predicate pushdown.

Answer (score 1):

`array_contains` does not generate a data source filter predicate so no connector could could ever have a chance to support this for a predicate pushdown.

---

`array_contains` creates a [ArrayContains](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L3046) Catalyst predicate expression that is not converted to a data source filter predicate when `DataSourceStrategy` planning strategy is requested to [translateFilter](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/DataSourceStrategy.scala?utf8=%E2%9C%93#L451).

There is `Contains` predicate expression among the expressions supported but not `ArrayContains`. Think you should report it in the [Spark JIRA issue tracking system](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SPARK).